# Margin propriety related with body tag

Tags: html, css

Could someone make me understand please, The effect of change values of margin's propriety is related with external element that has declared it's propriety.
Then by saying this, For me don't make sense we mess with it's propriety when we are talk about body tag since in practice we should see this change effect  related with  and  tag

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you @OUTC-K? Setting the body margin causes the body to shrink by the margin's amount inside the html element, which is the top level element of the browser. In effect, the margin is the gap between the html element and the browser element.

Comment: [What is the css box model?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#what_is_the_css_box_model) -> _"Margin box: The margin is the outermost layer, wrapping the content, padding, and border as whitespace between this box and other elements; size it using margin and related properties."_ setting the margin to the body element will shrink its inner boxes and will make a gap between the body border and the root element in terms of document flow (so elements positioned in other ways (eg: absolute) won't be affected by body margin)

Comment: @Can O' Spam  i'm not sure too by i guess i'm the one who follow you, by the way for the explanation.